# What happens to talk show giveaways that don't match the audience?

Tags: talk-shows

Inspired by [an answer to this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34849/40573).

In his answer, BrettfromLA says he received a package of Hanes underwear. Many gifts, such as money, gift cards, or CDs, would be usable by any recipient. But underwear and other personal items have a high chance of not matching the recipients.

So what happens if an audience member gets something they can't use/don't like? Do they just refuse it? Take it and give it away? Or do talk shows check for audience members' sizes/preference before taping?

Comment: Any show giving away sized stuff likely has multiple sizes in stock based on general clothing bell curves, or stick to one size fits all items. Im sure sized underwear is a really really rare giveaway.

Comment: As a non–tea-drinker who once got a large hamper full of just about every product Lyons Tea make, I cut a deal with a taxi driver where I paid for my taxi ride home in tea.